# Can I modify state directly when using React with MobX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

The only reason why I should not do it is to let react update view. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly
  But It seems that MobX-react do these dirty work for me. I just need to mark `this.state` as observable, and everything works as expected. Are there any drawbacks? I don't want to throw all states into a giant store.

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/wv3yopo0/1016/)

Code:

```
const {observable, computed} = mobx;
const {observer} = mobxReact;
const {Component} = React;

@observer
class Form extends React.Component{
    @observable state = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
    };

    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    render() {
        return  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>
                    Name:
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.username} onChange={event => this.state.username = event.target.value} />
                    </label>
                    <div>username: {this.state.username}</div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>;
    }

    handleSubmit(event: Event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state.username);
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <Form />
        <mobxDevtools.default />
    </div>
, document.getElementById('mount'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can name it `form` instead of `state` and it won't care, its bypassing React's `setState` and rerender mechanism. React `setState`, in addition to merging state updates to the component, also tells your component to rerender. React components have a `forceUpdate`.

MobX also does both, by updating `observable`s you also send a message to connected `observer` components to update themselves. And having a central state store is an established pattern with React.

Comment: So, `setState` does nothing more than schedule a vdom diff?

Comment: @Zen It does so, after merging the input to the actual state.

Answer (score 4):

It's best to bypass `state` altogether and just put the observable data directly on the class.

**Example ([JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/veratitewo/edit?js,output))**

```
const {observable, computed} = mobx;
const {observer} = mobxReact;
const {Component} = React;

@observer
class Form extends React.Component{
    @observable username = '';
    @observable password = '';

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    render() {
        return <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>
                Name:
                <input type="text" value={this.username} onChange={event => this.username = event.target.value} />
            </label>
            <div>username: {this.username}</div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>;
    }

    handleSubmit(event: Event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.username, this.password);
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <Form />
    </div>
, document.getElementById('mount'));
```

Comment: I came across this answer & I was trying to implement it in my project. However I get error `Parsing error: Leading decorators must be attached to a class declaration` since it seems it just works with classes. Can you take a look at it, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67004479/how-to-change-state-using-mobx-react-from-any-component-in-the-tree is there to accomplish this with function components?